# get horizontal and vertical spacing in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, spacing

I am implementing a grid view in my application and I want to get the horizontal spacing between consecutive rows and vertical spacing between consecutive columns within grid view using java code.

Is it possible?
Is there any direct methods to get spacing?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try in Java

```
mGridView.setHorizontalSpacing(4);
mGridView.setVerticalSpacing(4);
```

Or in XML

```
<GridView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"  
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp">
```

Answer (score 1):

If your minSdk is 16 then you can use `mGridView.getHorizontalSpacing()` or `mGridView.getVerticalSpacing()`.

If not, you can set in the xml layout `android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_spacing"` and in the code use `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grid_spacing)`.

This way, you can change the size in just one place and it'll effect both the xml-layout and the code.

Inside /res/values/dimens.xml add this line -

```
<dimen name="grid_spacing">10dp</dimen>
```